# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method ' query'

Tags: php, laravel-4, command, migration, laravel-artisan

//while migrate this file i got an above error

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class SubjectOrderForExam extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subjectOrderingForExam', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('id', true);
            $table->integer('subjectId');
            $table->integer('classId');
            $table->integer('sectionId');
            $table->string('subjectName', 255);
            $table->integer('orderingNo');
            $table->enum('isDelete', ['0','1'])->default('0');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('subjectOrderingForExam');
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is nothing todo with the error. Can you shour your error stack here.

Comment: @KrisRoofe pardon me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not using all the needed namespaces for this.

As an example, in one of my laravel 6 projects i include the following at the beginning (note the **Schema** ns):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
```

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2 version. Is it applicable for laravel 4.2?

Comment: well that's different. By looking at the Laravel 4.2 docs maybe you should create your schema like this (note that im not using Blueprint):

Schema::create('subjectOrderingForExam', function($table) . . .

and maybe your "id" column should be of type "increments" not integer.

$table->increments('id');

Try both and tell us if that worked out for you. Also, it would be good to specify the laravel version you're using in the title of the post :)
 .